# How can a pirated blu-ray be released online before the official blu-ray release?

Tags: distribution, piracy

The Birdman (2014) Blu-ray has a release date of February 17, 2015.  However, while surfing the internet I found a pirated copy of the movie's Blu-ray, 13 days before the official release.

So my question is: how can a movie's pirated Blu-ray be released on the internet before it's actual release?

Comment: Uh, *"released in internet"* and labeled *"Birdman.2014.1080p.BluRay.x264"*? Might I ask on *what* kind of site you found that "release" and if it might not simply be the case of incorrent labeling (or any other way of obtaining that BluRay "inofficially" before the release)?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Link redirects me to RARBG site.

Comment: "Teh Scene" is explained on [this Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warez_scene).

Comment: @JagranRakesh please refrain from linking to pirated content on this site.  thank you.

Comment: @Dfrock42, see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759158/python-parsing-html) User posted a pirated link, but still visible. but when i post a link it was removed, why you removed link ?

Comment: StackOverflow and Movies.SE are two different sites; why are you comparing the two?

Answer (score 9):

Your link was removed as it pointed to a torrent website.  That particular blu-ray was probably a "[screener](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screener)".  Screeners are given to members of [AMPAS (Academy of Motion Picture Arts and Sciences)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academy_of_Motion_Picture_Arts_and_Sciences), as not all movies are viewed in theaters and not all movies up for nomination have been released on DVD/blu-ray prior to voting.

In some instances, movies found on these sites are culled from DVDs/blu-rays released in other countries, since not all countries release the same title on the same day.  On other cases, the movies have been "leaked" by hackers or employees of the film studio or one of the post-production studios.  i.e., a [workprint of X-Men: Wolverine](http://www.hitfix.com/blogs/motion-captured/posts/wolverine-workprint-leaks-online) was leaked by one of the companies in charge of adding special effects.

Comment: The nfo for that "release" clearly states the source is a retail release (thus not a screener). Which is possible, since for instance Canada will get a BD [in two weeks](http://www.blu-ray.com/movies/Birdman-or-The-Unexpected-Virtue-of-Ignorance-Blu-ray/117701/), and it is fairly common that such releases "leak" weeks before their intended release.

Comment: Don't always believe the NFO files.  Every "group" wants to make their mark, and many NFO's are shamelessly incorrect.  It'll say it's 720p when it's a VHS rip.  I mean, it *might* be a retail rip, but I've had a mint screener of that movie for a couple months already.

Comment: SPARKS is a well-known scene group. If the name says "1080p.BluRay" and the NFO claims the source is a retail BD, they don't get away with a upscaled DVD screener. Moreover, [screeners are less and less the sources of leaks](https://medium.com/message/pirating-the-2015-oscars-hd-edition-6c78e0cb471d).

Comment: Interesting.  Plus, at least on DirecTV, some movies get released in theaters and on PPV on the same day.  I'm sure some of the HD stuff comes from there too.

Comment: @JohnnyBones see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759158/python-parsing-html) User posted a pirated link, but still visible. but when i post a link it was removed, why you removed link ?

Comment: @JagranRakesh I flagged that question for moderator attention stating that it links to pirated content.